# WSL (Hyper-V-VmSwitch) connects/reconnects/does something with my networking every 3-10 minutes and it stutters my sound

Tags: windows-10, networking, audio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clicking-sound

I have ran WSL2 for a while with a Kali installation, I do most of my programming work there. Since a while ago, I can't recall exactly when, I started having issues with sound stuttering and was troubleshooting with LatencyMon and other programs to try and figure out what the problem was. Link to thread of microsoft support forums (with zero good replies): (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466983/sound-stutterslagspops-on-host-machine-whenever-hy.html#answer-474652).

I have linked my sound stuttering to when WSL (Hyper-V-VmSwitch) does something with the network

[HyperVNetwork logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5vAR.png)

```
Networking driver in Virtual Machine is loaded and the protocol version is negotiated to the most recent version (Virtual machine ID 4E28C58C-BE6A-451D-A5E8-E944A5756E4D).

NIC 4E28C58C-BE6A-451D-A5E8-E944A5756E4D--FC785225-9131-5661-AC0C-3A157C61AE15 (Friendly Name: ) successfully connected to port 32097E04-6456-4FBB-AA70-A91218419EFB (Friendly Name: 5E03A28A-6836-45A1-AE15-0C24DBFDE003) on switch E4E1D1EB-6009-48AD-8CC8-E195490F0524(Friendly Name: WSL).

The operation 'Create' succeeded on nic 4E28C58C-BE6A-451D-A5E8-E944A5756E4D--FC785225-9131-5661-AC0C-3A157C61AE15 (Friendly Name: ). Port 32097E04-6456-4FBB-AA70-A91218419EFB (Friendly Name: 5E03A28A-6836-45A1-AE15-0C24DBFDE003) successfully created on switch E4E1D1EB-6009-48AD-8CC8-E195490F0524 (Friendly Name: WSL).

The operation 'Delete' succeeded on nic 0E162F26-4FC8-452F-972A-43E573F7DEFA--FC785225-9131-5661-AC0C-3A157C61AE15 (Friendly Name: ).
```

How can I stop this from happening every few minutes? I try to run a **wsl --shutdown** or **wsl -t kali-linux** but it keeps spinning up again, and even if it's running it's still doing these things and causing sound issues. I added info to a github issue on this matter and they responded to another person stating that if you had files relating to wsl in your recent files folder it would spin up automatically, so I cleared out my recent files and it spins up anyways.

Technically, I just need help getting rid of my sound problems. I use kali in windows so often it would be a real shame to get rid of it but I can't live with sound stuttering every two minutes either.

LatencyMon complained about various things but the images in the microsoft thread above is with a bunch of processes, including spotify or youtube running while it was doing it's thing so they are not too accurate and I have already re-installed and upgraded/downgraded all drivers relating to sound, network and graphics about four times now.

I also read somewhere here that this issue can be related to windows Dns Service not running but it's already running.

Comment: That sounds frustrating.  If you don't get a good answer here (and I'm doubting it, unfortunately), then I'd recommend opening an issue on the ... Oh, wait - I see you did already.  Good!  For anyone else who comes across this, please also see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7178) on the Microsoft WSL Github.  You also might want to try the [WSL Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/) - Sometimes a few WSL developers check in there as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty frustrating. I've gone over to vmware in the meantime because I just can't live with the audio problems. I hope someone has an answer. :)

Comment: Sorry for replying to an old question, but this has been happening for me too for weeks and it's driving me insane too. I am using a Debian distro not kali and I have the exact same events happening every minute. It's also even worse when gaming everything stutters, no input registered for half a second. Did you by any chance figure something out about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: @KiKoS Sorry dude, switched to VMware on this machine and the problems went away. I made an issue on their github and did something with their feedback hub about it way back when I asked about this but got nothing out of it really.

Comment: Got it! Thank you again for your reply.